# Can't link Random Value output to any nodes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I'm working on a python script that creates a geometry node. So far so good but I couldn't get the output value from Random Value node to connect to Less Than node (or pretty much any node).

Geometry node looks like this:
[image]

And here is the python snippet:

```
nodes = node_group.nodes

index = nodes.new(type="GeometryNodeInputIndex")

random_value = nodes.new(type="FunctionNodeRandomValue")
random_value.data_type = 'INT'

less_than = nodes.new(type="FunctionNodeCompare")
less_than.data_type = 'INT'
less_than.operation = 'LESS_THAN'

links = node_group.links
links.new(nodes["Group Input"].outputs['Min in group'], random_value.inputs[4])
links.new(nodes["Group Input"].outputs['Max in group'], random_value.inputs[5])
links.new(nodes["Group Input"].outputs['Seed'], random_value.inputs[3])
links.new(index.outputs[0], random_value.inputs[7])

links.new(random_value.outputs[0], less_than.inputs[2])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello ! I think the same question was asked a few days ago, Under the hood there is actually one socket per output type and the unused ones are dynamically hidden so chances are your integer output is higher than index 0

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks! You were right, the index for this output is 2.

Comment: @matte It would be great of you to write a short answer to this and mark it as "Accepted Answer" so that this question shows up as solved. Thank you!